# Seleniumwire dont intercept HTTPS if user-data-dir is defined

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, https, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I try to intercept requests by seleniumwire.

If I dont use option `--user-data-dir` everything is fine. All requests are showed by `driver.requests`.

But I need parse some sites with authentication. So I provide in `--user-data-dir` option profile with *remembered* accounts. But in this case HTTPS requests not intercepted.

Command `driver.requests` showes only requests to google-ads and some other trash.

So how to intercept HTTPS requests while providing profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should to disable all proxy extensions.

`options.add_arguments("--disable-extensions")`